# Getting mail room calendar using IBM Domino Access Services 9.0.1 (REST service)

Tags: wcf, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am trying to access the mail room calendar item using Domino Access Service 9.0.1. Able to get the mail box details of user using http:///mail/test.nsf/api/calendar/events . Similarly i want to access the mail room calendar item, how can i do it?
Thanks Anil

Comment: What is the "mail room"? That's not a standard Domino term, so you're going to have to explain what it means and how it has been implemented in your environment.

Comment: Mail room is like conference room what we arr having in microsoft exchange.I am Able to access the user's calendar item by using http://<host>/mail/test.nsf/api/calendar/events,but i don't know how to access the mail room/conference room calendar.

Comment: It sounds like it must be in the Rooms & Resources database. You can read a little about that here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27002648. I don't know if the Domino Calendar Service API can get to that. You might ahve to use the Domino Data Service API for that, and if that's the case you'll need more detailed knowledge of how the data is phsyically stored in the database. Unfortunately, that's not an area I can help you with.

Answer (score 1):

The Domino calendar service is not designed to read events from the rooms & resources database.  If you just want to find out when a room is available, you could use the [Domino freebusy service](http://extlib.openntf.org/Projects%5Cpmt.nsf/0/783A19E01A5CC35886257C1A00730CCD/%24file/Domino%20Freebusy%20Service.pdf).  The freebusy service is a separate REST API available with the extlib from OpenNTF.  If you want to read event details from rooms & resources, the Domino data service is an option.  As Richard said in the comments section, that could get complicated.

Comment: Thanks Richard and Dave for the response.My application requires the status as well as event details.Dave it would be great if you point me in data service which one i have to use.